# Forcing all to https via htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, https

So in my htaccess file for a Wordpress site I have:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

I want all urls whatever entered to go to https://example.com (https, no www.)

At the moment this works well here:

```
http://example.com = https://example.com 
www.example.com = https://example.com
```

However when on a page it doesn't work:

```
http://example.com/page/ = example.com/page/
www.example.com/page/ = example.com/page/
```

How can I make this go to the https version?

Answer (score 0):

Change you htaccess file to below and it will work for you.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^$ https://example.com/? [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Still not working: http://domain.com/page/ = domain.com/page/
www.domain.com/page/ = domain.com/page/

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have done to the trick...

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: With www ? I do not think so.